# Does Python select a 'default' tuple item/index?

Tags: python, tuples

Imagine the following function:

```
def getMinAndMax(numbers):

  return min(numbers), max(numbers)
```

What will happen if I do this?

```
num = getMinAndMax([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Will `num` assume the value of the first item in the tuple, `min`, or will something else happen?  I know I can just try it, but I'm looking for some defined Python behavior here.

Comment: I don't get it. Your function will return the tuple (1, 5) (and this will be the value of num).

Comment: will trying it not show you the behaviour?

Comment: Why would "something else happen"? Tuples are ordered and immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function returns the two-element tuple `min([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), max([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` which evaluates to `1, 5`. So the statement

```
num = getMinAndMax([1,2,3,4,5])
```

will bind the name `num` to the tuple `(1, 2)` and you can access the individual values as `num[0]` and `num[1]`. Python does allow you, though, to use what's usually referred to as a *unpacking assignment* which looks like this:

```
nmin, nmax = getMinAndMax([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

That binds each name to a succeeding element of the tuple on the right-hand side and allows you to use the values without indexing. If you need a tuple of the results your formulation is simplest, though of course the expression `(nmin, nmax)` will re-create it from the second one.

Comment: Looking back, this was a dumb question in the first place.  Good answer though

Answer (score 2):

`num` will be a tuple. The value of `num` will be equal to `(1,5)` in your example. Python does not check types by default, so you can safely assign whatever value of whatever type you want to whatever variable.